# Let X, Y be independent RVs. Calculate the following probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables with positive integers values, with distribution
$$ P(X=i)=P(Y =i)= \frac{1}{2^i},i∈N^∗$$
Find the following probabilities.

(i) $P(\max(X, Y ) ≥ i)$

(ii) $P(X = Y)$

(iii) $P(X > Y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go back to more elementary problems when facing this kind of questions.

1. $max(X,Y) \geq i$ is equivalent to $X \geq i$ or $Y \geq i$.

So $P(max(X,Y) \geq i) = P(X \geq i) + P(Y \geq i) - P(X \geq i, Y \geq i) = 2 \sum_{j=i}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} - \left( \sum_{j \geq i} \frac{1}{2^j} \right)^2$

2. Don't forget that $X$ and $Y$ are independent: $P(X = Y) = \sum_i P(X=i, Y = i) = \sum_i P(X = i) P(y = i) = \sum_i \frac{1}{2^{2i}}$
3. Use conditional probabilities: $P(X > Y) = \sum_i P(X > Y | Y = i) P(Y=i) = \sum_i P(X > i) \frac{1}{2^i} = \sum_i \frac{1}{2^i} \sum_{j > i} \frac{1}{2^j}$

I hope my advices will help you with future problems.

Comment: Independence has nothing to do here. The sum is obtained because you consider the union of two events (ie A OR B). You would obtain a product if you had the intersection of two events (ie A AND B)

Comment: Nope. You are trying to mix my answer with martini's one. Both are correct, but cannot be used together. Mine says that $P(max(X,Y) \geq i) = P(X \geq i || Y \geq i) = P(X \geq i) + P(Y \geq i)$. Basicaly I say that $max(X,Y) \geq i$ if and only if $X \geq i$ or $Y \geq i$. Martini considers the negation of this event.

Comment: @PAM But, you answer to 1. is not correct, it's not true that $X = i$ and $Y = i$ are disjoint. To see that note that your answer implies that $$ P(\max(X,Y)  \ge 1) = 2 $$

Comment: @martini Indeed thanks! I correct that! :)

Comment: @martini Your solution to (i) remains more elegant, I confess!

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**. Recall that independence gives you that 
$$ \def\P#1{\mathbf P\left[#1\right]}\P{X \in A, Y \in B} = \P{X\in A}\P{Y\in B} $$
for every $A,B \subseteq \def\N{\mathbf N}\N^*$.

(i) Note that we have 
$$ \P{\max(X,Y)\ge i} = 1 - \P{\max(X,Y)<i} = 1 - \P{X < i, Y < i} $$
and use independence.

(ii) Here the law of total probiability will help you, conditioning on $Y$ gives 
$$ \P{X=Y} = \sum_{i\in \N^*} \P{X=Y \mid Y = i}\P{Y=i} 
     = \sum_{i\in \N^*} \P{X = i\mid Y = i}\P{Y=i}
$$
Now independence will help you again.

(iii) Use symmetry in $X$ and $Y$ of the problem to conclude $\P{X<Y}=\P{Y<X}$. Now use (ii).